# To display system clock time in LCD format

Tags: python, pyqt4

I just want to display system clock time in LCD format. I also want the time to be displayed using `hh:mm:ss` format. My code is below. But when I run it, it is not as I expected. Can anyone explain why?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showlcd)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.showlcd()

    def initUI(self):

        self.lcd = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Time')

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.lcd)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.show()

    def showlcd(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.lcd.display(text)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QLCDNumber` has a fixed digit display ([`QLCDNumber.digitCount`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qlcdnumber.html#digitCount-prop)) and its default value is `5`. So your text is truncated to the last 5 characters. You should set an appropriate value (8 in your case).

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showlcd)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.showlcd()

    def initUI(self):

        self.lcd = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.lcd.setDigitCount(8)          # change the number of digits displayed
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Time')

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.lcd)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.show()

    def showlcd(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.lcd.display(text)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```